# How to add new fields to existing users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm having a big deal - the meteor app I've been developing the last weeks is finally online. But, for an update, I need to add a field to my users profile.

I thought that walling a methods with the following code would work :

```
updateUsrs_ResetHelps: function(){
  if(Meteor.users.update({}, {
    $set: {
      'profile.helps': []
    }
  }))
    console.log("All users profile updated : helps reset");
  else
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Error 500: updateUsrs_ResetHelps', 
      'the update couldn\'t be performed');
}
```

The problem is that my users have the classic Meteor.accounts document, whith emails, _id, services, profile, etc... but, in the profile, they don't have a .helps fields. I need to create it.

For the future users, I've modified the accounts creation function to add this fields when they sign up, but for the 200 users I already got signed up, I do really need a solution.

EDIT : Might it be because of the selector in the update ? Is a simple {} selector valid to update all the users / documents of the collection at once ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Mongo documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/):

> By default, the update() method updates a single document. Set the
>   Multi Parameter to update all documents that match the query criteria.

If you've already taken care of adding the field for new users and you just need to fix the old ones, why not just do it one time directly in the database?

Run `meteor` to start your application, then `meteor mongo` to connect to the database. Then run an update on records where the field doesn't already exist. Something like:

```
db.users.update({"profile.helps": {"$exists": false}}, {"$set": {"profile.helps": []}}, {multi:true})
```

The Mongo documentation specifies the multi parameter as:

> Optional. If set to true, updates multiple documents that meet the
>   query criteria. If set to false, updates one document. The default
>   value is false.

Comment: Well,  didn't know I could do that, thanks you a lot, you save me :)
Waiting or an answer, I've tricked it by fetching all user, and looping into them with a while to update them one by one. So now they all have the fields, but I guess there is a faster way to change globally the value for every doc / users ?

Still, thanks you a lot for the tip :)

Comment: @DavidPanart, I updated my answer to show the use of the `multi` parameter to update multiple records.